# How to control each spark worker node to do some special job?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

For example, I have a spark cluster with 6 slaves (each slave has 4 CPUs). And I have thousands of files should be processed by the slaves. Those files are located at some FTP.

Since I have total 24 CPU cores, how can I assign tasks to each slave?

This is the pseudo code work flow (by python)

1. Get all file names list as `all_files_list` and `all_files_length`=`len(all_files_list)`
2. Define file process function

   ```
   # this function will be executed by each slave
   # download files from files list, and process the files by each slave
   def file_process(files_list, slave):
       files = download_files_from_ftp(files_list)
       process_file_list_by_slave_at_cpu(files, slave)
   ```
3. Call the file process function at spark driver program

   ```
   sc = spark.sparkContext
   for slave in range(6): # 6 slave
           index_begin = (all_files_length/6)*(slave) # files list index begin
           index_end = (all_files_length/6)*(slave+1)# files list index end
           files_list = all_files_list[index_begin:index_end] # the files list which should be processed by each cpu of slaves
           files_list_rdd = sc.parallelize(files_list) # create rdd 
           file_process(files_list_rdd, slave) # call the file process function defined at step 2
   ```

Any help to implement the logic by spark cluster programming ?

Comment: I do not think it is possible to assign on which slave and cpu you want to execute your part of the job. Why do you even need it?

Comment: Thanks @Hlib for the comment. Actually I just want to let the slaves process my task (files analysis) in the distributed way.  I have modified my question to just share the tasks by slaves. Would you help  share some suggestion again? I will be grateful for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, forget about slaves and cpus in you spark code. It is responsibility of a cluster manager; it will schedule and re-schedule (in case task fails), etc.

Second. I do not think it is even possible to create 6 RDDs and then each process by one slave in parallel. (but it is possible to create an RDD which contains 6 files inside, and then process it)

Third. If intrinsically, you want to process each of N files  by using 4 cores, then you need to write spark app which process single file, configure you cluster only for 4 core per an application `spark.cores.max 4`, and finally, submit N application to your cluster, by using bash/python/whatever script. This way, you cluster will perform 6 apps simultaneously, but you cannot be sure that 4 cores of one app will be on the same machine.

Comment: Thanks @Hlib for the suggestion. I finally completed my task with your help. And my code is here for others reference (https://github.com/ybdesire/machinelearning/tree/master/16_spark/file_process_distributed)